# nbdev_build_docs error: nbformat.validator.NotebookValidationError: 'name' is a required property

Tags: python, jupyter

I love the concept of `nbdev` but had trouble setting it up; following instructions at:
https://nbdev.fast.ai/example.html or https://nbdev.fast.ai/tutorial.html

The `nbdev_build_docs` was giving the following error:

```
nbformat.validator.NotebookValidationError: 'name' is a required property

Failed validating 'required' in notebook['properties']['metadata']['properties']['language_info']:
```

Any ideas if how to solve it?

Answer (score 0):

First of all; I think this was caused by using the wrong import statement at the top.

Just in case you are lookin for a manual fix, you can do so by updating the following raw info in `index.ipynb` via `vi` (p.s. you'll need to make it match your case):

```
"metadata": {
  "kernelspec": {
   "display_name": "Python 3.8.5 64-bit",
   "name": "python3"
  },
  "language_info": {
   "codemirror_mode": {
    "name": "ipython",
    "version": 3
   },
   "file_extension": ".py",
   "mimetype": "text/x-python",
   "name": "python",
   "nbconvert_exporter": "python",
   "pygments_lexer": "ipython3",
   "version": "3.8.5"
  }
 }
```

p.s. this replaced the erroneous one:

```
"metadata": {
  "kernelspec": {
   "display_name": "Python 3",
   "language": "python",
   "name": "python3"
  }
 }
```

p.s. I was using it on `Github CodeSpaces` which are awesome!